# MobX: Since strict-mode is enabled, changing (observed) observable values without using an action is not allowed

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-react-lite

My context looks like this:

```js
class AuthStoreClass {
    authUser = null

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this)
    }

    login = async (params) => {
        const { data: { data: authUser } } = await loginUser(params)
        this.authUser = authUser
    }
}

const AuthStoreContext = React.createContext(null);

export const authStoreObject = new AuthStoreClass()

export const AuthStoreProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    return <AuthStoreContext.Provider value={authStoreObject}>{children}</AuthStoreContext.Provider>;
};
export const useAuthStore = () => {
    return React.useContext(AuthStoreContext);
};
```

And I am using the context somewhere else in a component:

```js
const LoginPage = observer(() => {
    const authStore = useAuthStore()
    ...
    authStore.login(...)
```

The last line reports the following warning:

> [MobX] Since strict-mode is enabled, changing (observed) observable values without using an action is not allowed. Tried to modify: AuthStoreClass@1.authUser

Everything works as expected. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Your `login` function is `async` and you need to use `runInAction` inside, or handle result in a separate action, or use some other way of handling async actions:

```js
import { runInAction, makeAutoObservable } from "mobx"

class AuthStoreClass {
    authUser = null

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this)
    }

    login = async (params) => {
        const { data: { data: authUser } } = await loginUser(params)
        
        // Wrap all changes with runInAction
        runInAction(() => {
          this.authUser = authUser
        })

        // or do it in separate function
        this.setUser(authUser)
    }

    // This method will be wrapped into `action` automatically by `makeAutoObservable`
    setUser = (user) => {
        this.authUser = user
    }
}
```

That is because, citing the docs, every step ("tick") that updates observables in an asynchronous process should be marked as action. And the code before the first `await` is in a different "tick" than the code after `await`.

More about async actions (you can even use generators!): https://mobx.js.org/actions.html#asynchronous-actions

In MobX version 6 actions are enforced by default but you can disable warnings with `configure` method:

```
import { configure } from "mobx"

configure({
    enforceActions: "never",
})
```

But be careful doing it though, the goal of `enforceActions` is that you don't forget to wrap event handlers and all mutations in an `action`. Not doing it might cause extra re-runs of your observers. For example, if you changing two values inside some handler without action then your component might re-render twice instead of once. `makeAutoObservable` wraps all methods automatically but you still need to handle `async` methods and `Promises` manually.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can also change the function to use the `yield` syntax, negating the need for `runInAction`.

```
*login() {
    const { data: { data: authUser } } = yield loginUser(params)
    this.authUser = authUser
}
```

Comment: Can you link some documentation for the yield syntax?

Answer (score 0):

another possible solution is to define the methods in the class constructor and declare it as `action`

```
constructor() {
  makeAutoObservable(this, {
    login: action
  })
}
```

import { action, makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";

```
class AuthStoreClass {
    authUser = null

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this, {
           login: action
        })
    }

    login = async (params) => {
        const { data: { data: authUser } } = await loginUser(params)
        this.authUser = authUser
    }
}
```