# MobX running a function after async action

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have an issue with MobX as I'd like to call `onSortHandler` as well as `loadingCallback` after an **async action** in my store but the call order is misaligned due to the **async action**. The added complexity of the issue is that `onSortHandler` triggers a function which uses a **computed value** calculated by the given **action**.

Here is my action in the store:

```
loadFurniturePage = async (pageNumber: number, pageAmount: number) => {
        const nextPage = await agent.FrontEnd.getNextFurniturePage(pageNumber, pageAmount); <-- I suppose while waiting here, the finally block get called. (See it below)
        nextPage.forEach((furniture: IFurniture) => {
            furniture.type = furniture.typeInString;
            this.furnitureMap.set(furniture.id, furniture)          
        });
    }
```

Here is the place where I call the action above:

```
loadFurniturePage(pageNumber, pageAmount).finally(() => { <-- this code block should be called after the action finishes it's running.
    onSortHandler(selectedSortByValue); 
    loadingCallback(false);
});
```

And this is the computed value I use when calling `onSortHandler`:

```
get getAllFurniture() {
    return Array.from(this.furnitureMap.values())
}
```

Does anybody have an idea, how to solve this?

Comment: hi. Is `this.furnitureMap.set(furniture.id, furniture)` an `async` function?

Comment: @EhsanNazeri it is not, as far as I know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MobX: Since strict-mode is enabled, changing (observed) observable values without using an action is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64770762/mobx-since-strict-mode-is-enabled-changing-observed-observable-values-withou)

Answer (score 1):

After `async` function call if you continue to change mobx observables, wrap that code in [`runInAction`](https://mobx.js.org/actions.html#runinaction)

```js
loadFurniturePage = async (pageNumber: number, pageAmount: number) => {
        const nextPage = await agent.FrontEnd.getNextFurniturePage(pageNumber, pageAmount);
        runInAction(()=>{
        nextPage.forEach((furniture: IFurniture) => {
            furniture.type = furniture.typeInString;
            this.furnitureMap.set(furniture.id, furniture)          
        });
})

    }
```

```js
loadFurniturePage(pageNumber, pageAmount).finally(() => {
    runInAction(()=>{
    onSortHandler(selectedSortByValue); 
    loadingCallback(false);
})

});
```